# X++ : what's the IDE for learning X++?

Tags: x++

Please suggest me the IDE for learning X++.Also give me the url to download it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be supported by Visual Studio?

Comment: i'm a beginner for x++. Dont know where to start? Visual studio 2010 is enough for developing in x++?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a substitute to a google search...

Comment: The first question is : why do you want to learn X++ ?

Comment: X++ is the programming language in Microsoft Dynamics AX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To develop in X++, you must use Microsoft Dynamics AX. The software is not available for download and must be bought and installed through a Microsoft partner.

However, you can learn X++ through some good textbooks, such as the ones listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/cc546579.aspx

And through classroom training courses offered through Microsoft, such as this one: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Course.aspx?ID=80303A&Locale=en-us

Or, you can simply browse the MSDN library for detailed information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx